# Personal Internet use monitoring

Tags: windows, proxy, monitoring

How could a (Windows) desktop application be created to monitor the amount of time spent on a particular website?

My first idea was to play with the [Host](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/hosts.htm) file to intercept requests, log, and proxy.  This feels a bit clunky; and I suspect my program would look like malware.

I feel like there is a smarter way? Any ideas?

Comment: The HOSTS file is used for DNS - you'd want to capture the layer 7 requests & log them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route the traffic through a scriptable proxy and change the browser settings to point to that proxy.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool similar to what you are looking for called [K-9 Web Protection](http://www.k9webprotection.com/). It is more used for parents to monitor what their kids are up to when hooked up to the internet. I have installed this for my niece's computer with good results and praises as it blocks, content filter, restrict internet times. This may be OTT for your needs but worth a shot as you can see what sites were visited.

The other, is to use a dedicated firewall monitoring solution such as [IPCOP](http://www.ipcop.org) which is a Linux based distribution with a sole purpose in providing a proxy, stateful packet inspection (SPI) firewall, Intrusion Detection System (IDS).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Net Nanny was another similar product

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by monitoring active connections via netstat, or if you need more advanced data you can install [The Windows Packet Capture Library](http://www.winpcap.org/) and get any data about network use, and inside your desktop app, find network traffic that relates to 'spending time' on a website (which might just be GET requests for you, but I don't know), and record various statistics as required.